# can somebody help me with mysql triggers syntax

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1064, eventtrigger

SQL query: Documentation

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `test` AFTER INSERT ON `test_series`
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE ids INT;
set ids=1;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT NEW.no_of_exam
  FROM test_series WHERE serise_id = NEW.series_id;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
OPEN cur;
ins_loop:
LOOP FETCH cur INTO ids;
IF done THEN LEAVE ins_loop;
END IF;
INSERT INTO test_details (series_id,test_no) VALUES(new.series_id,);
ids=ids+1 END LOOP;
CLOSE cur;
END;
//
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT NEW.no_of_exam FROM test_series WHERE serise_id = ' at line 7

Comment: Also follow these guidelines please: [ask] and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can't `DECLARE` wherever and whenever you want. All `DECLARE` statements must be on top of a `BEGIN` block.

In your code, in between some `DECLARE` statements, there is a `set ids=1;` statement. And it is violating `DECLARE` requirements.

Please make following changes in your code.

```
BEGIN
    -- all declares should be just below a 'begin'
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE ids INT;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR 
        FOR SELECT NEW.no_of_exam FROM test_series 
             WHERE serise_id = NEW.series_id;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    -- now start your biz logic after all 'declare' statements.      
    SET ids=1;

    OPEN cur;
        ins_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO ids;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE ins_loop;
            END IF;
            INSERT INTO test_details (series_id,test_no) VALUES(new.series_id,);

        SET ids=ids+1;
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
END;
```

BTW: You are reading cursor into a variable but not using! Why? I believe you want to use it as `test_no` in insert statement. If yes, then `insert` statement needs following change:

```
INSERT INTO test_details (series_id,test_no) VALUES(new.series_id, ids);
```

**Document Reference**:

[***DECLARE Syntax***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare.html)

> *`DECLARE`* is permitted only inside a *`BEGIN ... END`* compound statement
>   and must be at its start, before any other statements.
>
> Declarations must follow a certain order. Cursor declarations must
>   appear before handler declarations. Variable and condition
>   declarations must appear before cursor or handler declarations

Comment: as i need to loop the insert statement as many times as the value which was fetch in cur.

Comment: ok... did you test the changes suggested?? you got the desired result ??

Comment: yes, i got the desired result by doing some modification, please see my previous answer i just updated and suggest if anything wrong in that.